# C# - Posting XML to MVC site

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc, httpwebrequest

I am trying to post an XML string to a local website running on my machine.
My XML is generated from the following c#:

```
public string CreateOrderToSend(CreateOrderModel OrderModel, byte[] data, string username, string password, string searchPack)
        {
                // new string for storing orderPlacement xml instructions
                string xml_OP = "";
                // start populating with data (maybe from params?)
                using (TextWriter strWriter = new Utf8StringWriter())
                {
                    using (XmlTextWriter xmlWriter = new XmlTextWriter(strWriter))
                    {
                        // not sure if this is needed
                        xmlWriter.WriteStartDocument(false);

                        xmlWriter.WriteWhitespace("\n");
                        xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("OrderPlacement");
                        xmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("xmlns", "hidden");
                        xmlWriter.WriteWhitespace("\n\n");

                        xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("Authentication");
                        xmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("xmlns", "hidden");
                        xmlWriter.WriteWhitespace("\n");
                        xmlWriter.WriteElementString("Username", username);
                        xmlWriter.WriteWhitespace("\n");
                        xmlWriter.WriteElementString("Password", password);
                        xmlWriter.WriteWhitespace("\n");
                        xmlWriter.WriteEndElement(); // Authentication
                        xmlWriter.WriteWhitespace("\n\n");

                        xmlWriter.WriteElementString("FileReference", OrderModel.FileRef); // FileReference
                        xmlWriter.WriteWhitespace("\n\n");

                        xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("Address");
                        xmlWriter.WriteWhitespace("\n");
                        xmlWriter.WriteElementString("PropertyIdentifier", OrderModel.Address1);
                        xmlWriter.WriteWhitespace("\n");
                        xmlWriter.WriteElementString("Street", OrderModel.Address2);
                        xmlWriter.WriteWhitespace("\n");
                        xmlWriter.WriteElementString("Town", OrderModel.Address3);
                        xmlWriter.WriteWhitespace("\n");
                        xmlWriter.WriteElementString("Postcode", OrderModel.Address4);
                        xmlWriter.WriteWhitespace("\n");
                        xmlWriter.WriteEndElement(); // Address
                        xmlWriter.WriteWhitespace("\n\n");

                        xmlWriter.WriteElementString("UPRN", OrderModel.UPRN); // UPRN
                        xmlWriter.WriteWhitespace("\n\n");

                        xmlWriter.WriteElementString("NewBuild", OrderModel.NewBuild.ToString().ToLower()); // NewBuild
                        xmlWriter.WriteWhitespace("\n\n");

                        xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("SitePlanEmbeddedObject"); // (base64 - stream)
                        xmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("Name", "pdfName.pdf");
                        xmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("ContentType", "Application/Pdf");
                        xmlWriter.WriteString(data.ToString()); // base64 string
                        xmlWriter.WriteEndElement(); // SitePlan
                        xmlWriter.WriteWhitespace("\n\n");

                        xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("Pack");
                        xmlWriter.WriteWhitespace("\n");
                        xmlWriter.WriteElementString("PackCode", searchPack);
                        xmlWriter.WriteWhitespace("\n");
                        xmlWriter.WriteEndElement(); // Pack (foreach - can be more than one pack)
                        xmlWriter.WriteWhitespace("\n\n");

                        xmlWriter.WriteEndDocument(); // OrderPlacement
                        xmlWriter.Flush();

                        xml_OP = strWriter.ToString();
                    }
                }
                string newstring = xml_OP;
                return newstring;
        }
```

In order to move the data to the site, I am running this (xmlContent is populated with the above xmlWriter method):

```
postXMLData("http://localhost:41092/Home/Order/", xmlContent);
```

My postXMLData method looks like this.

```
public string postXMLData(string destination, string xmlContent)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < NumberOfRetries; i++)
        {
            string byteValue = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xmlContent));
            try
            {
                HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(destination);
                byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(xmlContent);
                request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
                //request.ContentType = "text/xml; encoding='utf-8'";
                request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
                request.Method = "POST";
                Stream req = request.GetRequestStream();
                req.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                req.Close();

                HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
                Stream respStream = response.GetResponseStream();
                string respString = new StreamReader(respStream).ReadToEnd();
                {
                    string responseStr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
                    return responseStr;
                }
                return null;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                if (i == NumberOfRetries)
                {
                    return null;
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

I am running a simple mvc website with an almost-empty controller.
**When running the postXMLData method, a breakpoint is hit in my controller, but the value of incomingXML is null.**
When dragging 'this' into my watch window, the value under this.Request.Form.Allkeys[0] is equal to `"<?xml version"`.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Order(string incomingXML)
        { // breakpoint is here
            var content = this.Request.Form.AllKeys;
            return null;
        }
    }
```

I must be fairly close if there is something in the AllKeys field, but it seems it's cutting short?
Or is an MVC site the wrong solution to pass the xml? Maybe a web api?
Help please!

Comment: Please show us an example of your XML you are posting

Comment: See latest edit.

Comment: May I ask why XML, and not JSON?  It will also be better if you create a class, containing all of those properties, and serialize/deserialize to XML if you have to, or JSON.

Comment: My MVC site is an attempted replicate of another system that I will be sending the data to, my site is just for testing. This other system **has** to receive XML, not JSON.
Any ideas on why the data is not sending across properly?

Comment: Show the xml string, as you are sending it to the client. Show xmlContent

Comment: Remove all `xmlWriter.WriteWhitespace("\n");` calls. Use `xmlWriter.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;` setting.

Comment: Same result as before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update:

The XML was not parsing correctly due to the "=" signs I had in my xml attributes, weirdly. 
I commented these out and the XML value was successfully being stored in the field:

```
this.Request.Form.AllKeys[0]
```

I will perhaps have to parse the attribute values separately to the XML and dynamically insert them within my MVC.